# Returning null in a method that accounts for multiple conditions

Tags: if-statement, methods, syntax, null, return

Consider the following method:

```
private static String method (String string) {
    if (string.equals("conditionOne")) {
        return value;
    } else if (string.equals("conditionTwo")) {
        return symbol;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Let's say I am checking for two conditions, `conditionOne` and `conditionTwo`. Also, assume that some other part of the program ensures that only these two cases will ever happen. Since the method has to return something for all cases to avoid a compiler error, is it okay to return `null` for the final `else` block just for syntactical purposes since that part will never execute?

**Edit**: For clarity, I'd like to mention that the compiler gives me an error ("Expecting return statement") if I don't include that last `else` block. Other than  to returning null (or an empty string, as pointed out by Anthony below), is there another way to write this method so that this does not happen?

Thanks

Comment: The people developing stagefright thought the same. Who would pass more imagedata then the size of the image? Your code will not lead to a big exploit, but to a (may) bad user experience when the code crashes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're describing a very common scenario while programming. You *intend* for a certain thing to never happen, but the compiler also knows it *could* happen. The proper way to handle such code paths is to ensure that they are never reached, generally by throwing an [`AssertionError`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/AssertionError.html) or a `RuntimeException` such as [`IllegalArgumentException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalArgumentException.html), [`IllegalStateException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalStateException.html) or [`UnsupportedOperationException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/UnsupportedOperationException.html). This is referred to as [failing-fast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fail-fast).

In your case I would throw an `IllegalArgumentException` as that's clearly what's happened - your method expects exactly two inputs; anything else is forbidden and you should fail-fast in such cases. Effective Java Item 38 also discusses this.

```
private static String method (String condition) {
  if (condition.equals("conditionOne")) {
    return value;
  } else if (condition.equals("conditionTwo")) {
    return symbol;
  }
  throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid condition '" + condition +"'");
}
```

Now you can be confident the only inputs this function will support are the ones it is designed to support. Even better, anyone calling your method incorrectly will get a clear, actionable error message.

The Guava User Guide has a good [overview of different kinds of failures](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/ConditionalFailuresExplained) and when you should raise them.

You could also avoid this issue other ways - namely by defining a better method signature. It looks like you're defining a ["stringly-typed"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15065110/113632) API; using an enum would help prevent callers from passing in erroneous parameters. See also Effective Java Items 50 and 30.

---

In rare cases (generally when dealing directly with user input) you'll want to fail-soft rather than fail-fast. This is common with [confirmation dialogs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1885525/113632); if you ask the user to enter "Yes" or "No" it's generally sufficient to simply check whether they entered "Yes" - whether they entered "No" or "Uhhhh", you'll just treat it as not-"Yes".

Comment: could you also place the thrown exception into an `else` block?

Comment: You could, but there's no need since the other blocks all `return`, so the `else` block is redundant.

Comment: so even though you may know that this exception may never be thrown, it is just generally safer to include it for the reasons explained above, right?

Comment: Right; if you return `null` or `""` you are *assuming* the `else` will never be reached; if you throw an exception you are *asserting* it is unreachable, and therefore can be confident your assumption is correct. Returning filler values is a classic source of really unpleasant bugs.

Comment: Regarding my currency program, I created a new `void` method that works perfectly. Once again, I needed to initialize the variables to avoid compiler error. Regarding good practices, with this `void` method, since I'm not returning anything, is it initializing the variables to an empty or `null` value fine? And since there's nothing to return, I don't need to throw a new exception for failing-fast, right? I've posted a new question (http://stackoverflow.com/q/38559519/5606164) for followup. I'd appreciate if you could provide your feedback once  more. Thanks!

Comment: You should still throw an exception if your code's assumptions are violated (in this case, as an `else` block). This is a good practice regardless of anything else - what would your code do if someone passed in a currency other than USD or CNY? Even better, doing so here means you won't need to set the local variables to `null`. Here's a [cleaned up](http://pastebin.com/iwXbXFau) version of your function, but yes please post new questions rather than asking followups in comments. You'll get better answers.

Comment: You'd also avoid the whole issue by simply defining two separate methods - `convertUsdToCny()` and `convertCnyToUsd()` that each just take a `BigDecimal` parameter.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118182/discussion-between-a-is-for-ambition-and-dimo414).

Answer (score 1):

As you have defined the function as returning a String, it would be more correct to have

```
if (string.equals("conditionOne")) {
    return value;
} else if (string.equals("conditionTwo")) {
    return symbol;
} else {
    return "";
}
```

Comment: This only offloads the problem - yes you avoid `NullPointerException` but now all your code has to check that the result is not empty. This pattern leads to hard-to-maintain code that is difficult to work with and reason about.

Answer (score 1):

You can write something like this:

```
if (string.equals("conditionOne")) {
    return value;
} else if (string.equals("conditionTwo")) {
    return symbol;
}
return "";
```

or like this:

```
string rval = "";
if (string.equals("conditionOne")) {
    rval = value;
} else if (string.equals("conditionTwo")) {
    rval = symbol;
}
return rval;
```

or like this

```
if (string.equals("conditionOne")) {
    return value;
} else if (string.equals("conditionTwo")) {
    return symbol;
}
throw;
```

edited.

Answer (score 0):

If you've already guaranteed that the string will always equal either `conditionOne` or `conditionTwo`, then writing the 3rd `else` condition is not necessary.

It's equivalent to adding code that does not check if it's either `conditionOne` or `conditionTwo`. It's better off to remove it.

**Edit** Seeing your edit, I would recommend the above solution of returning `""` since it's a string.

Comment: please see the **Edit** in my post